# how to ignore other discord channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, discord, discord.py

I'm looking for a code. that I get the live text from 1 discord channel and not from every channel

example

- **server 1**

  - channel a
  - channel b
  - channel c
- **server 2**

  - channel a1
  - channel b1
- **server 3**

  - channel a2
  - channel b2
  - channel c2

I would like to see example of channel b1 only the text and then not of all channels/servers

i have now this code

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == [id_of_channel_b1]:"channelid"
    

client.run (<mytoken>)
```

I hope someone can help me

for questions please ask me maybe can explain a little better if you don't understand the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

remove `[]`

```
if message.channel.id == id_of_channel_b1:
```